# Service Fabric stateless service behaviour

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-service-fabric

I'm developing a **Service Fabric Stateless App** and there´s some strange behaviour when I try to create a `service bus queue client`.

In the `Servie.cs` class:

```
public class ServiceBusQueueService : IQueueService<SbMessage>
{
    private readonly QueueClient _client;

    public ServiceBusQueueService(string queueName)
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ServiceBus.ConnectionString");

        // When executes this line, it throws an exception
        _client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
    }
  }
```

The exception:

---

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a
>   problem in 'C:\SfDevCluster\Data_App_Node_4\App\etc\etc\app.exe'.
>
> Additional information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The
>   address of the error was at 0x809d81d6, on thread 0x19a4. The error
>   code is 0x80131623. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the
>   unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this
>   bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which
>   may corrupt the stack.

I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: Are connection string and queue name correct? Remember that 'QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString' has restriction on connection strings.

Comment: have you tried debugging on your local dev cluster

Comment: Im using eventhub and have had the same issue with the same error code.

Comment: Debug on your local cluster and look for an inner exception. Also, make sure you have diagnostic logging turned on and you are managing exceptions properly in your code.

Comment: Did you end up finding out what this was?

Comment: I've created a [GitHub issue for it](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/86).

Comment: I got the same issue. it turned out that I forgot to define one parameter in *.xml in ApplicationParameters.

Comment: What's the inner exception? It seems odd that this would throw if connection string is valid and queue is found.

Comment: Had the same exception, turned out to be cancellationToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.MaxValue). It seems the time span must be smaller than the equivalent of int.MaxValue milliseconds (about 24 days). Found out in the Diagnostics log, the debugger was no good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same error using VS2015 update 3 , when running in the local fabric emulator ( will test if it happens on a real cluster) its a native error with the low level service bus run time . All i can say is to report it at this point.

Nuget packages
Service fabric C# 2/5.1.150
windows azure service bus.  3.3.1